# RuntimeError: The current Flask app is not registered with this 'SQLAlchemy' instance. Did you forget to call 'init_app', or did you create multiple

Tags: python, flask

I made some login, register program using Flask and Runtime error has occurred.
<RuntimeError: The current Flask app is not registered with this 'SQLAlchemy' instance. Did you forget to call 'init_app', or did you create multiple 'SQLAlchemy' instances?>

Here are my codes.

```
main
   app.py
   templates
      index.html
   instance
      users.db
   auth
      __init__.py
      auth.py
      models.py
      templates
         login.html
         register.html
   home
      __init__.py
      home.py
      templates
         dashboard.html
```

main/app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import secrets


db = SQLAlchemy()
migate = Migrate()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secrets.token_hex(16)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    
    db.init_app(app)
    migate.init_app(app, db)

    from auth.auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    from home.home import home as home_blueprint

    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

main/auth/**init**.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

auth = Blueprint("auth", __name__, template_folder="templates")
```

main/auth/auth.py

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, request, session
from auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime
from app import db
from auth import auth
import hashlib
import re


@auth.route('/test')


@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        username = request.form['username'] 
        password = request.form['password'] 
        email = request.form['email']
        birth = str(request.form['birth'])
        
        ...

        if not checkDupId(username):
            return render_template('register.html', error)

        ...

def checkDupId(user_id):
    dup_user_id = User.query.filter_by(username=user_id).first() //This code have error.
    if dup_user_id is not None:
        return False
    else:
        return True
    
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        user = User.query.filter_by(
            username=username, password=hash_password(password)).first() //This code have error, too.
        
        ...
```

main/auth/models.py

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    birth = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
```

If all code is in one file: app.py (without blueprint), It goes well. But If I use blueprint to split the files, Runtime error has occurred. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue as this. I based my solution off of this post: [Flask and SQLAlchemy, application not registered on instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499428/flask-and-sqlalchemy-application-not-registered-on-instance)

I'll try come up with a solution with your code above.

1. In your main/auth/models.py I would import and initialize the db object in that file. I.E:

   [image]
2. In your main/app.py folder, import db from your model file. I.E

   from auth.models import db

then you can init the app using the db object.
[image]

This is what worked for me. Hopefully it will work for anyone who is coming across a similar issue